# How to run this nodejs "express-remote" application?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, totem

I am running ubuntu and I am trying to control my totem functions via my mobile. I came across this application but I am not sure how to make it work !!

I have nodejs installed and I have already run the npm install command which did not return any errors.

The link below is the github page but unfortunately does not contain my documentation on how to use it.

https://github.com/yaacov/express-remote